# ¿Por qué mi tarjeta se desplaza al seleccionar un ataque?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flex

Verán, estoy iniciando en todo este mundo de la programación mediante un curso en Platzi. lo he completado paso a paso y he seguido cada instrucción.

En este curso, tenía que desarrollar un juego, lo cual estoy a punto de terminar; sin embargo, al seleccionar un ataque, la sección en donde se encuentra la información del enemigo se va desplazando hacia abajo y no sé como solucionarlo.

Agrego todo el código para dar contexto, el error según yo debe estar en el `container-enemigo` (ln:142-153):

```js
let ataqueJugador
let ataqueEnemigo
let vidasJugador = 3
let vidasEnemigo = 3

function iniciarJuego() {
  let sectionSeleccionarAtaque = document.getElementById('seleccionar-ataque')
  sectionSeleccionarAtaque.style.display = 'none'

  let sectionReiniciar = document.getElementById('reiniciar')
  sectionReiniciar.style.display = 'none'

  let botonMascotaJugador = document.getElementById('boton-mascota')
  botonMascotaJugador.addEventListener('click', seleccionarMascotaJugador)

  let botonFuego = document.getElementById('boton-fuego')
  botonFuego.addEventListener('click', ataqueFuego)
  let botonAgua = document.getElementById('boton-agua')
  botonAgua.addEventListener('click', ataqueAgua)
  let botonTierra = document.getElementById('boton-tierra')
  botonTierra.addEventListener('click', ataqueTierra)

  let botonReiniciar = document.getElementById('boton-reiniciar')
  botonReiniciar.addEventListener('click', reiniciarJuego)
}

function seleccionarMascotaJugador() {
  let sectionSeleccionarMascota = document.getElementById('seleccionar-mascota')
  sectionSeleccionarMascota.style.display = 'none'

  let sectionSeleccionarAtaque = document.getElementById('seleccionar-ataque')
  sectionSeleccionarAtaque.style.display = 'flex'

  let inputHipodoge = document.getElementById('hipodoge')
  let inputCapipepo = document.getElementById('capipepo')
  let inputRatigueya = document.getElementById('ratigueya')
  let spanMascotaJugador = document.getElementById('mascota-jugador')

  if (inputHipodoge.checked) {
spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = 'Hipodoge'
  } else if (inputCapipepo.checked) {
spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = 'Capipepo'
  } else if (inputRatigueya.checked) {
spanMascotaJugador.innerHTML = 'Ratigueya'
  } else {
alert('Selecciona una mascota')
reiniciarJuego()
  }

  seleccionarMascotaEnemigo()
}

function seleccionarMascotaEnemigo() {
  let mascotaAleatoria = aleatorio(1,3)
  let spanMascotaEnemigo = document.getElementById('mascota-enemigo')

  if (mascotaAleatoria == 1) {
spanMascotaEnemigo.innerHTML = 'Hipodoge'
  } else if (mascotaAleatoria == 2) {
spanMascotaEnemigo.innerHTML = 'Capipepo'
  } else {
spanMascotaEnemigo.innerHTML = 'Ratigueya'
  }
}

function ataqueFuego() {
  ataqueJugador = 'FUEGO'
  ataqueAleatorioEnemigo()
}
function ataqueAgua() {
  ataqueJugador = 'AGUA'
  ataqueAleatorioEnemigo()
}
function ataqueTierra() {
  ataqueJugador = 'TIERRA'
  ataqueAleatorioEnemigo()
}

function ataqueAleatorioEnemigo() {
  let ataqueAleatorio = aleatorio(1,3)

  if (ataqueAleatorio == 1) {
ataqueEnemigo = 'FUEGO'
  } else if (ataqueAleatorio == 2) {
ataqueEnemigo = 'AGUA'
  } else {
ataqueEnemigo = 'TIERRA'
  }

  combate()
}

function combate() {
  let spanVidasJugador = document.getElementById('vidas-jugador')
  let spanVidasEnemigo = document.getElementById('vidas-enemigo')

  if(ataqueEnemigo == ataqueJugador) {
crearMensaje("EMPATE")
  } else if(ataqueJugador == 'FUEGO' && ataqueEnemigo == 'TIERRA') {
crearMensaje("GANASTE")
vidasEnemigo--
spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
  } else if(ataqueJugador == 'AGUA' && ataqueEnemigo == 'FUEGO') {
crearMensaje("GANASTE")
vidasEnemigo--
spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
  } else if(ataqueJugador == 'TIERRA' && ataqueEnemigo == 'AGUA') {
crearMensaje("GANASTE")
vidasEnemigo--
spanVidasEnemigo.innerHTML = vidasEnemigo
  } else {
crearMensaje("PERDISTE")
vidasJugador--
spanVidasJugador.innerHTML = vidasJugador
  }

  revisarVidas()
}

function revisarVidas() {
  if (vidasEnemigo == 0) {
crearMensajeFinal("FELICITACIONES! Ganaste :)")
alert("GANASTE!!!")
  } else if (vidasJugador == 0) {
crearMensajeFinal('Lo siento, perdiste :(')
alert("Perdiste")
  }
}

function crearMensaje(resultado) {
  let sectionMensajes = document.getElementById('resultado')
  let ataqueDelJugador = document.getElementById('ataque-del-jugador')
  let ataqueDelEnemigo = document.getElementById('ataque-del-enemigo')

  let nuevoAtaqueJugador=document.createElement('p')
  let nuevoAtaqueEnemigo=document.createElement('p')

  sectionMensajes.innerHTML=resultado
  nuevoAtaqueJugador.innerHTML=ataqueJugador
  nuevoAtaqueEnemigo.innerHTML=ataqueEnemigo

  ataqueDelJugador.appendChild(nuevoAtaqueJugador)
  ataqueDelEnemigo.appendChild(nuevoAtaqueEnemigo)
}

function crearMensajeFinal(resultadoFinal) {
  let sectionMensajes = document.getElementById('resultado')

  sectionMensajes.innerHTML = resultadoFinal

  let botonFuego = document.getElementById('boton-fuego')
  botonFuego.disabled = true
  let botonAgua = document.getElementById('boton-agua')
  botonAgua.disabled = true
  let botonTierra = document.getElementById('boton-tierra')
  botonTierra.disabled = true

  let sectionReiniciar = document.getElementById('reiniciar')
  sectionReiniciar.style.display = 'block'
}

function reiniciarJuego() {
  location.reload()
}

function aleatorio(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

window.addEventListener('load', iniciarJuego)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap');
.body {
  background-image: url(./assets/ilustracion-pintura-digital-escena-paisaje-hermosas-montanas-verdes-prados-arboles_467123-4517.png);
  background-size: 400vh;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

.titulo {
  color: #ff0505;
  width: 1270px;
  height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#seleccionar-mascota {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.subtitulo {
  color: #16425b;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.tarjetas {
  display: flex;
}

.tarjeta-de-mokepon {
  width: 156px;
  height: 60px;
  color: #16425b;
  background-color: rgb(45, 201, 92);
  padding: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: lobster;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tarjeta-de-mokepon img {
  width: 80px;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked+label {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

label:hover {
  width: 170px;
  height: 70px;
}

#boton-mascota {
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: lobster;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 5px solid white;
}

#seleccionar-ataque {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.tarjetas-ataques {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.boton-ataque {
  display: flex;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  font-family: lobster;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mensajes {
  color: black;
  background-color: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
}

#boton-reiniciar {
  border: none;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: lobster;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 40px;
  width: 112px;
}

.container-jugador {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  right: 11rem;
  top: 8rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.container-enemigo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  right: -12rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: bisque;
}

@media(max-width:720px) {
  .tarjetas,
  .tarjetas-ataques {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  <h1 class="titulo">MOKEPON! </h1>
  <section id="seleccionar-mascota">
    <h2 class="subtitulo">Elige tu mascota:</h2>
    <div class="tarjetas">

      <input type="radio" name="mascota" id="hipodoge" />
      <label class="tarjeta-de-mokepon" for="hipodoge">
                        <p>Hipodoge</p>
                        <img src="./assets/mokepons_mokepon_hipodoge_attack.png" alt="Hipodoge">
                    </label>

      <input type="radio" name="mascota" id="capipepo" />
      <label class="tarjeta-de-mokepon" for="capipepo">
                        <p>capipepo</p>
                        <img src="./assets/mokepons_mokepon_capipepo_attack.png" alt="Capipepo">
                    </label>

      <input type="radio" name="mascota" id="ratigueya" />
      <label class="tarjeta-de-mokepon" for="ratigueya">
                        <p>Ratigueya</p>
                        <img src="./assets/mokepons_mokepon_ratigueya_attack.png" alt="Ratigueya">
                    </label>

      <button id="boton-mascota">Seleccionar</button>
    </div>

  </section>
  <section id="seleccionar-ataque">

    <h2>Elige tu ataque:</h2>
    <div class="tarjetas-ataques">
      <button id="boton-fuego" class="boton-ataque">Fuego </button>
      <button id="boton-agua" class="boton-ataque">Agua </button>
      <button id="boton-tierra" class="boton-ataque">Tierra </button>

    </div>

    <div id="mensajes">
      <p id="resultado"></p>

      <section id="reiniciar">
        <button id="boton-reiniciar">Reiniciar</button>
      </section>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="container-jugador">
        <p id="vidas-jugador">3</p>
        <p id="mascota-jugador"></p>
        <div id="ataque-del-jugador">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-enemigo">
        <p id="vidas-enemigo">3</p>
        <p id="mascota-enemigo"></p>
        <div id="ataque-del-enemigo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor adjúntanos tu HTML y CSS en su respectivo formato, no en imágenes.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev creo que ya, pero la verdad no sé si lo hay hecho bien, es mi primera vez en esta comunidad

Comment: Veo que los ataques no se pueden seleccionar... no será al seleccionar la mascota? y por cierto, cual sería el problema en sí?... de que se mueve el contenido de abajo al hacer hover? o me equivoco?

Comment: @Cris223511.dev el problema es que al seleccionar un ataque el container-enemigo se desplaza hacia abajo. Con respecto a lo del ataque, si se puede; sin embargo alguien mas editó mi codigo, supongo que lo consideraría innecesario para la solucion del problema

Comment: @Cris223511.dev https://codepen.io/AndresFSH/pen/rNrXMyr

Comment: Entiendo ahora sí, adjuntaré el código en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás dando un espacio encima (un `top`) al `container-jugador`, solo tendrías que quitarlo:

```css
.container-jugador{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    right: 11rem;
    top: 8rem; <!-- esto lo quito -->
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: bisque;
}
```

Y también, hice flexible al contenedor que encierra a `container-jugador` y `container-enemigo` para que estos estén uno al lado del otro (aunque ya estaban uno al lado del otro, pero al quitar el `top`, los contenedores de adentro se desalineaban al no ser flexibles), y pues con esto ya quedaría:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

---

[**Código completo.**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/yLqmaEE)